# Mixing C and C++ global variable

Tags: c++, c, global, linkage

On my project, we have a header file that looks akin to this:

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
  int x;
} MyStruct;

extern "C" MyStruct my_struct;
```

Previously, it was only included in C++ source files. Now, I have need to include it in C files. So, I do the following:

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
  int x;
} MyStruct;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" MyStruct my_struct;
#else
MyStruct my_struct;
#endif
```

I understand that 
    extern "C"
will declare the my_struct global variable to be of C-linkage, but does this then mean that if I include this file in C-compiled files as well as CPP-compiled files that the linker will determine my intention that in the finally-linked executable, I only want one MyStruct for C and CPP files alike to use?

Edit:

I've taken the advice of the accepted answer. In the header, I have

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
  int x;
} MyStruct;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" MyStruct my_struct;
#else
extern MyStruct my_struct;
#endif
```

And in the cpp source file, I have

```
extern "C" {MyStruct my_struct;}
```

And everything builds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since this is the header file, your C branch should use `extern` as well:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" MyStruct my_struct;
#else
extern MyStruct my_struct;
#endif
```

Otherwise, you will end up with multiple definitions of the `my_struct` in every translation unit where the header is included, resulting in errors during the linking phase.

The definition of `my_struct` should reside in a separate translation unit - either a C file or a CPP file. The header needs to be included as well, to make sure that you get proper linkage.

Comment: Hi. I've updated my question to reflect your changes in my code. In C, it makes sense to me that if I declare my_struct extern in the header that at link time it would find the variable in a compiled object file as long as I've added a non-static variable of the same type and name somewhere in a non-header source file. How does this work for C++? It seems to me that there's a discontinuity in meaning between 'extern "C"' in the header vs. in the source file. From which line does the actual allocation of the variable happen in the cpp translation? In the header or in the cpp?

Comment: @SanJacinto Globals work in C++ in the same way as they do in C, i.e. there needs to be a declaration and a definition. The declaration has `extern`, and goes in the header; it does not result in an allocation - it's a promise that there's going to be an allocation some place else. The definition, on the other hand, does not have `extern`, and goes in one of the CPP files. It is the definition that controls allocation: it needs to happen in the CPP file.

Comment: Ahh, so it's in bad form then to wrap my definition in the cpp source file with 'extern "C"' ? OK, thanks!