# Sharing A global variable between C and C++ Files

Tags: c++, c, scope

I have two files.  One is a C file the other is a C++ file.

in main.C

```
char globalvar = 0;

int main()
{
     .....
}
```

in main.h

```
extern char globalvar;
```

in file2.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

int function()
{
    globalvar = 5;  //ERROR, globalvar is undefined.
    ...

}
```

So basically I have a project that is part C and part C++.  I have a global variable declared in main.c  I have been successfully able to access this global in all of the C files, but the C++ files do not recognize it.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what is going on?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm no expert in `c++` but did you try `extern C` and then include C header file into cpp code?

Comment: `extern "C" char globalvar;` as of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18260029/mixing-c-and-c-global-variable I do not know cpp well though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `main.h` should look like

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
extern char globalvar;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

To make sure globalvar has `C` linkage.

Comment: Nice one, as always. A simple question, can we do the `extern "C" in the `.cpp` file while including `main.h`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes it will work but you need to do this in all `.cpp` files which include `main.h`